# Auto Increment in FTL

Tags: loops, frontend, auto-increment, freemarker

I am already iterating through a list and need another variable to hold an integer value which should auto increment along with the list.

Can some one let me know how to do that?

My FTL version is 2.3.16

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually need the index of the list item you are at? The modern solution to that is adding `?index` (0-based) or `?count` (1-based) after the loop variable, such as:

```
<#list somelist as someItem>
  ${someItem?index}
</#list>
```

However, you are using an ancient version (consider upgrading...), where there's no `?index` and `?count`, but there's a variable created by adding `_index` after the name of the loop variable:

```
<#list somelist as someItem>
  ${someItem_index}
</#list>
```